# Select specific columns determined by the headers

Tags: r, header

Below is my example data:

```
set.seed(13435)
x <- data.frame("Alex"=sample(1:5),"1Alx1"=sample(6:10),"Peter"=sample(11:15))
```

and it will return the an example table:

```
  Alex X1Alx1 Peter
1    2       8    15
2    3       7    12
3    5       6    14
4    1      10    11
5    4       9    13
```

I want to extract new table by selecting specific keyword from the header. For example, I want to only extract my new table with keyword "Al" from the header and the new table should be like below:

```
  Alex X1Alx1 
1    2       8   
2    3       7    
3    5       6   
4    1      10   
5    4       9
```

I know there is method by using %in% to select one variable but how do I extract all the data by using keywords from header?

Comment: `dplyr::select(x, contains("Al"))`.

Comment: I have error > Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "contains"

Comment: Update your `dplyr` package, the functions comes with the most recent versions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` from `base R`

```
x[grep("Al", names(x))]
#      Alex X1Alx1
#1    2      8
#2    3      7
#3    5      6
#4    1     10
#5    4      9
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. One more question, what should I do if I multiple condition?

Comment: @Alex it depends on your condition.  suppose you have `Al` and `Bl` then `x[grep("Al|Bl", names(x))]`